# Need to decode a RTSP stream to V4l2loopback with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I am trying to decode an RTSP stream to a V4L2 device on a raspberry pi zero.

first i create a loopback device this way..

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=25
```

Then i try to decode the RTSP stream to a virtual V4L2 device. I would prefer if i could sink it to YUYV format..

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.138:8554/unicast ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! tee ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video25
```

When i inspect the V4L2 device with this...

`v4l2-ctl -d 25 --list-formats`  , i get this...

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture
```

When i try to play it back with VLC , nothing happens.

```
sudo cvlc --v4l2-dev=25 --v4l2-width=640 --v4l2-height=480 --v4l2-fps=30 --vout=mmal_vout v4l2:///dev/video25
```

I suspect the gstreamer pipeline is not correct. I am new to gstreamer and i am poking a little bit in the dark there.

Could anybody give me some tips on what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.